# Default constructor with all parameters given default values?

Tags: c++, class, object, oop, constructor-overloading

I was reading the book by Joyce Farell on C++, and it's saying that **a default constructor is the one with no arguments**. I understood it without any hiccups. **But things started getting worse after it says that if you set default values to all arguments in the constructor it still is called default constructor.**

But I think it is still parameterized constructor as we can override the values by passing arguments when calling the constructor.

Here's the code:

[image: Default or parameterized constructor]

Now, what shall I call this constructor? When creating the `employee e1` object, it is acting as the default constructor. But at the same time, when creating the `employee e2` object, the same constructor is acting as a parameterized constructor.

But the constructor is the same - hence it should be either default or parameterized, not both at the same time.

I don't think you can call it constructor overloading, as you are calling the same constructor, not different ones.

I am actually trying to clarify my concept. There is no any error in my code.

Comment: Authors would often time give up precision to simplify explantions. That or they don't proofread. It'd be more accurate to say a default c'tor is one that *may be invoked* without arguments. Like `C()`.

Comment: "*a default constructor is the one with no arguments*" - that is wrong.  It should say something more like "*a default constructor is the one **that can be called** with no arguments*" instead.

Answer (score 4):

From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor

> A default constructor is a constructor which can be called with no arguments (either defined with an empty parameter list, or with default arguments provided for every parameter).

A constructor which doesn't require arguments is a default constructor. This includes a constructor with parameters if all of the parameters have default values. Such a default constructor can also optionally be called with arguments. Being able to be called such a constructor with arguments doesn't make it any less of a default constructor because the arguments aren't required.

C++ doesn't recognize the notion of "parameterized constructor". If you mean a constructor with parameters, then the notion is not exclusive with default constructor. By that definition a constructor can be both parameterized and a default constructor.